# convert pointer to iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

I have 2 structs, that point to each other

```
struct Person{
  string name;
  string born;
  int age;
  Id* p_id;
};

struct Id{
  string id_number;
  Person* p_person;
};
```

those structs are stored in two vectors of ponters to those structures called vec_id and vec_person. 
I need function which finds Person in vec_person, and then deletes matching Id in vector vec_id. 
My problem is converting p_id to pointer.

example of my code :

```
std::vector<Person*> vec_person;
std::vector<Id*> vec_id;
vector <Person*>::iterator lowerb=std::lower_bound (vec_person.begin(), vec_person.end(), Peter, gt);
//gt is matching function which is defined elsewhere
//peter is existing instance of struct Person
// lowerb is iterator, that works fine.
vec_id.erase((*lowerb)->p_id);
//gives error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Person*>::erase(Person*&)’|
//if i can convert pointer (*low)->pnumber to iterator, it would be solved(i guess).
```

Thx for help guys

Comment: Stop storing pointers in containers (unless you need polymorphism - even you have polymorphism you might wrap it with a class or use std::shared_ptr/std_unique_ptr)

Comment: "My problem is converting p_id to pointer." But `p_id` is *already* a pointer in your example!

Answer (score 6):

To convert an iterator `it` to a pointer, use the expression `&*it`.

To convert a pointer-to-int rvalue (e.g., ... ) to a `vector<int>::iterator`, use the declaration:

```
  vector<int>::iterator it(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't just 'convert' from a value (pointer in this case) to an iterator. You'd have to search for the value inside the vector and remove it. You could use the std::remove_if algorithm to remove certain values from a range. You might also consider not keeping two vectors if each Person is linked to an id, or maybe using a different container, such as a map.

Comment: I forgot to mention that vector is ordered with unique elements, so linear algortihm such as std::remove_if wont be a good choice. I also can use only vector container. Maybe lower_bound would be the best choice?

Answer (score 1):

I just found this solution

```
auto iter = vec.begin() + (pointer - vec.data());
```

Comment: Better to use `data()` rather than a non-standard function.

Comment: @Adrian yeah you're right

Answer (score 0):

```
auto p = std::equal_range( vec_person.begin(), vec_person.end(), Peter, gt );

if ( p.first != p.second )
{
   vec_id.erase( std::remove( vec_id.begin(), vec_id.end(), *p.first ), 
                 vec_id.end() );
}
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that elements are unque (and ordered). So replacing equal_range with lower:bound shloud work fine ?

Comment: @user2109307 In this case you should check that the iterator indeed points to the found element.