# Obtain iterator from pointer or reference

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, containers

I would like to know if it is possible to obtain an iterator to an object inside a container (e.g. `std::vector<...>`) by only having access to the object inside the container, e.g. through a reference (which implies we have access to a pointer to it using the `&` operator). For example, normally we declare an iterator as

```
std::vector<int>::iterator = vec.begin();
```

or

```
std::vector<int>::iterator = next(vec.begin(), idx);
```

but in the first example we are most probably about to iterate through the container, in order, while in the second example we know the index of the object we require. I would like to know if we can obtain the iterator to an object without knowing at which index it resides in the container, but if we do have a reference or a pointer to it, as explained above.

It might appear that this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209065/get-iterator-from-pointer), but it seems more like the OP wanted others to fix his code, rather than answering the general question, so the answers are not so satisfactory in my opinion. Also, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27948422) seems to say that we can initialize an iterator with a constructor, as shown below

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it(...);
```

but I have not been able to find any evidence of a constructor for the std::iterator class in the official documentation (and neither have I been able to find any documentation on std::vector<...>::iterator) so I am wary to use the constructor shown above, even if it compiles.

**NOTE**

I use `std::vector` as an example above, but ideally I would like this to work for any container, e.g. `std::list` or `std::deque`

Comment: You can go through an index. `vec.begin()+(pos-&vec[0])`

Comment: @KonradKapp then you should look for questions on how to find the index ;-)

Comment: @dyp yes, sorry for not being clear the first time round. I added a note to the question. I prefer using the iterator since I wish to use it as a break condition in a for loop. But that is beside the point :) The question is more generally on whether one could obtain an iterator in such a way (seems like something that should be easy, though)

Comment: A debug iterator implementation might want to store a pointer to some bookkeeping object in the iterator; in that case it might be impossible to construct an iterator just from a reference or pointer to the element (since the location of the element and the location of the bookkeeping object are unrelated). Of course, one can always implement some global LUT, but this gets ugly/slow very quickly.

Comment: As there are many types of iterators, it's unlikely that you will get a unified way to solve this for all of them. Of course you could just create the iterator of your choice and iterate until it matches your given item.

Comment: There is no general constant-time way. For deque, it simply isn't possible. For list, it would be possible, but the interface doesn't exist.

Comment: VS2015's implementation of vector debug iterators for example takes the pointer to the element plus a pointer to a `_Container_base` type, which is essentially such a bookkeeping object. This implementation does not have the single-argument constructor for vector iterators.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Specifically for `std::vector` (and other contiguous containers like `std::string`), given a pointer to an object in the vector `p`, we can simply do:

```
auto iter = v.begin() + std::distance(v.data(), p);
```

This is guaranteed by the contiguity contract. Note that random access is insufficient here, the above will not work for `std::deque`.

For any other container, there's no easy way of doing this. You'd have to just use `find_if`:

```
auto iter = std::find_if(c.begin(), c.end(), [p](auto const& o) { return &o == p; });
```

---

For *intrusive* containers, the iterator will be encoded into the object itself somehow so there will be some direct mechanism for converting `p` to an iterator. But that will be dependent on the intrusive container itself.

Comment: Note, however, that even for contiguous data structures you need to know *which* container does include the object. Trying to recover an iterator using a pointer to an object residing in a different container (or none at all) will fail.

Comment: @DietmarKühl to be clear, when you say *which* container, you actually mean which *type* of container, (as in whether it is `vector`, `list`, or `deque`, for example), and not which *instance* of a container? (for example between instances of `vector`?)

Comment: @KonradKapp He means which instance.

Comment: @KonradKapp No, you will need to know what instance you need to call `begin` on.

Comment: @KonradKapp: I mean the _instance_: if you have two vectors, `v1` and `v2` and your pointer (or reference) `p` points to an element in one of them, you'll need to know which of the two containers the elements points to. The operation `std::distance(v.data(), p)` is undefined unless `p` is in the half-open range `v.data()` to `v.data() + v.size()`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl yes, agreed. I had a silly moment there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `find` function---it returns an iterator---, supported on (almost?) all containers, to find your objects. If there are several objects which are equal under the `operator==`, iterate until the one with the same address has been found.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11 you can use the keyword auto to deduce the type, it makes writing the type easier.

If we know the index we can get an iterator to it by`begin() + index`.

And if we don't know the index we could use the [`std::distance()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) from begin and the other iterator, which will give us an iterator to the same element.

```
// if we know the index
auto it1 = begin(vec) + 4;
cout << *it1;

// if we don't know the index
auto p = begin(vec) + 3;
auto it2 = begin(vec) + distance(begin(vec), p+1);
cout << *it2;
```