# Construct std::vector<T>::iterator from pointer to object in vector

Tags: c++, iterator

Say I have a reference to an object which I know for sure is contained in a vector. Is it possible to create an iterator on the vector from the address of an object?

```
template<typename T>
class Container {
public:
    using iterator = std::vector<T>::iterator;
    iterator get_iterator(T &t) {
        // Realistically this would not be a public interface
        // and I would guarantee t is in m_vec
        return iterator(&t); 
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> m_vec;
}
```

Is this possible and well defined?

Comment: Just return a `T*` a pointer is a valid random access iterator.

Comment: @RichardCritten But it is not an iterator. For example it can't be compared to `std::vector<T>::end()`.

Comment: Doesn't this apply to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37101525/1025391 ?

Comment: You can use `return m_vec.begin() + (&t - m_vec.data());`. `std::vector::iterator` is random access, you can advance it by an arbitrary mumber of elements with the `+` operator. `std::vector` also stores it's elements contiguously, so you can subtract an element's address from the start of the vector's data to get it's offset.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux -- a bit more accurately, `T*` is a valid iterator type, but it's not necessarily the same type as `std::vector<T>::end()` returns. So, for example, if you have two pointers into your vector's data you can pass those pointers to an algorithm that expects a pair of iterators that designate a sequence.

Comment: @PeteBecker I meant to say that it's not a `std::vector<T>::iterator`, because that's what the question is explicitly asking for. Too late to edit my comment now :(.