# C++ convert list element pointer to list iterator

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I have a `std::list<T>` where `T` has some member functions, specifically the constructor of `T`, that would like to let some other classes know about the `T`'s address in the `list<T>`. This is so the other classes can later remove that node / splice it into another list / etc.

At construction the `T` doesn't yet have a place in the list, so for now it just gives out its own address (via `T::this`). I was wondering whether that `T*` could be convertible into a `list<T>::iterator`, which would then make available the standard container operations for removal/transfer/etc.

There doesn't seem to be an immediate answer (for lists) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101525/obtain-iterator-from-pointer-or-reference). I guess one workaround is to add a new `list<T>::iterator` field to `T`, and write the correct value in once it is known. The classes that can access the `T` can then access the correct iterator.

Interestingly, it does seem possible to roll my own naive implementation of a list node into `T`. In this model T encapsulates its own list capabilities, so that each T is also a list node and each T* is a list iterator. This would solve my problem. (Rough sketch follows below for interest.) I haven't built this out into a fully-fledged container as it seems to be quite a bit of work implementing it correctly ([like here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125955/my-first-implementation-of-a-linked-list-in-c/126007)). So I guess I will use the workaround, unless the community has any suggestions? Many thanks.

```
/* Base class for T provides list capabilities. Usage T : node<T>. */
template< class T >
struct node
{
    node<T>* next_; /* forward list. */

    /* Here the value is contained *outside* the node: */ 
    T* value() { return static_cast<T*> this; } /* uh-oh */
}

/* The iterator is essentially a convenience wrapper around node<T>*,
   can define operator++() etc. */
template< class T >
struct list<T>::iterator
{
    iterator( node<T>* some_node ) : node_( some_node );
    iterator operator++() { return node_ = node_->next_; }
    /* etc. */
    node<T>* node_;    
}

/* Usage: */
class Example : public node< Example >
{
    /* iterator is directly constructible from node< Example >*, 
       and Example derives from node< Example >, so class can 
       construct its own iterator. */
    operator list< Example >::iterator() { return this; } 

    /* Example's data members here as usual. */
    float data1_;
}
```

Comment: You can use boost::intrusive_list instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip! I'll have a look closely. I belatedly also note that both STL and Boost erase() and splice() require a reference to the list object/s -- the iterator/s by themselves are not enough to complete the operation. The hand-rolled basic list, with no cached size count, doesn't have this restriction.

Comment: Iterator gives you a reference to the list object, that's what iterators are for. It's going the other way around that is problematic.

Comment: Sorry - a fairly unclear comment on my part. To clarify, I was referring to the fact that erase() is a member function of list<T> (the "list object"). So to call erase() requires the list object as well as the iterator; my_list.erase( my_iterator ). my_iterator by itself is not enough and I don't think it will provide my_list. Thanks for the feedback btw.

Comment: Oh I see. erase is a member of all STL containers. You cannot get around it with a hand-rolled list because you need to update head and/or tail sometimes.

Comment: I believe that particular obstacle can be avoided using a sentinel node at each end.

Comment: Ah yes you are right, you can use sentinels.